# Lossy OR Lossless Decomposition

Tags: normalization, functional-dependencies, database-relations, database-management, lossless

Consider the relation R(A,B,C,D,E) with the set of F=(A->C,B->C,C->D,DC->C,CE->A)
Suppose the relation has been Decomposed by the relations R1(A,D),R2(A,B),R3(B,E),R4(C,D,E),R5(A,E)

Is this decomposition lossy or lossless?

i tried solving this question using the matrix method and i am getting the answer as lossless because i managed to get a row in the 5*5 matrix filled with one variable however the book from which i am solving gives the answer as lossy. which one is the correct answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a lossless decomposition for sure. The row corresponding to **R<sub>3</sub>** gets filled with one variable.

*As an aside*, if you have the above decomposition obtained using Bernstein Synthesis then just checking whether any of the decomposed relations consists of all the attributes of the key of the original relation **R** will ensure that it's a lossless decomposition. For example, **BE** is the key for the relation **R** in the example above. The decomposed relation **R<sub>3</sub>** consists of both the primary attributes **B** and **E** and hence this ensures a lossless decomposition.

Comment: thanks mate.i appreciate your help.i was getting my r3 filled with one variable as you said eariler so now i can be sure that that answer is lossless. its never good to trust the books blindly. also i didnt know about Bernstein synthesis.after your post i had a look at the topic and it has finally cleared all my doubts about this question.

Comment: @batman007 Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. :)